# How to Build a Monthly Table Out of Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a table like this:

Changes_table:

```
ID       StartDate  EndDate     RC  GC  ESG SF CC
12345   17/12/1972  30/09/1984  3   1   X1  B2  NULL
12345   01/01/1996  30/11/2007  3   1   X1  B2  R1
12345   01/12/2008  10/03/2015  3   1   X1  B2  R1
12345   01/05/2015  15/06/2015  3   6   O1  B2  NULL
12345   01/08/2015  31/12/9999  2   6   Q2  B1  NULL
```

And I would like to construct a monthly (8 months) for 2015 only table like this:

```
ID  Month   Year    RC      GC      ESG    SF        CC
12345   1   2015    3       1       X1      B2       R1
12345   2   2015    3       1       X1      B2       R1
12345   3   2015    3       1       X1      B2       R1
12345   4   2015    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
12345   5   2015    3       6       O1      B2      NULL
12345   6   2015    3       6       O1      B2      NULL
12345   7   2015    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
12345   8   2015    2       6       Q2      B1      NULL
```

But There is a a situation like this one:

```
ID       StartDate  EndDate     RC  GC  ESG SF CC
11111   17/12/1972  30/09/1984  3   1   X1  B2  NULL
11111   01/10/1984  30/01/1992  3   1   X1  B2  R1
```

In this case I would like to to include this employee with the last row of details I have on him. Output:

```
ID  Month   Year    RC      GC      ESG    SF        CC
11111   1   2015    3       1       Z1      B2       R1
11111   2   2015    3       1       Z1      B2       R1
11111   3   2015    3       1       Z1      B2       R1
11111   4   2015    3       1       Z1      B2       R1
11111   5   2015    3       1       Z1      B2       R1
11111   6   2015    3       1       Z1      B2       R1
11111   7   2015    3       1       Z1      B2       R1
11111   8   2015    3       1       Z1      B2       R1
```

Meaning, although the end date has passed because there were no other details that was recorded for this employee I would like to preserve the last details for him. Any idea how to differentiate between the two in the syntax?

The table was built according to the fields "StartDate" and "EndDate".

Rules:

1. IF the start date is something like "17/4/2015"  start Puting the
   data in month 4.
2. IF the end data is something like "1/5/2015" put 
   the data in month 5.  You can look at the output to see how I put in
   manually the data from Changes_table.

I case of :  01/01/2015-15/03/2015 and 16/03/2015-30/04/2015 
Then for 1/1/2015-15/03/2015 then pull data to 1,2,3 and the other for month 4.
I would really like your guidance for a simple and correct way to do that. 
Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking to aggregate the row results from the `changes_table`?  For example, if you have two rows that fall into the same month / year, you want to to be represented into one line?  Also, what about date ranges that span multiple months?

Comment: What if I get two records for one month. e.g. March in 01/01/2015-15/03/2015 and 16/03/2015-30/04/2015?

Comment: There won't be two rows that falls into two rows. The example I noted in the post are the most complicated.  Updated my post for a case like you noted.

Comment: The sample data he provides does not have any overlaps.  It would appear that RC, GC, etc  are values that are set for a time and they might "go away" for a time, then come back with a different value, or the same, but unique in time.  So he just wants to do a list, per month, showing which months had any value in them and what that value was.

Comment: The fields StartDate and EndDate are relevant for *all* the fields in that record. Meaning I put all of those in the month which I pull from those dates.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you are trying to do.  I would try something like what I have below.  I don't have a sqlserver handy, so can't check syntax, but you can do the debugging:

```
SELECT Changes_Table.id, AllMonths.Month, 2015, Changes_Table.RC,
       Changes_Table.GC, Changes_Table.ESG, Changes_Table.SF, Changes_Table.CC
  FROM Changes_Table
  RIGHT JOIN (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8))
       AS AllMonths(Month)
    ON ((year(Changes_Table.StartDate) < 2015) or
        (year(Changes_Table.StartDate) = 2015 and
         month(Changes_Table.StartDate) <= AllMonths.Month)) and
       ((year(Changes_Table.EndDate) > 2015) or
        (year(Changes_Table.EndDate) = 2015 and
         month(Changes_Table.EndDate) >= AllMonths.Month))
```

Comment: Hey Agapwlesu, Your answer has help me. I edit my post for another situation that I would be happy for your help how to differentiate.

Comment: If you have another situation that you need help with, you need to post another question, not add to a previous one.